# get contextmenustrip from toolstripmenuitem

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip, ownership

Do I use the `Owner`, `OwnerItem`, or the `Container` property?

What if the `ToolStripMenuItem` is a member of another tsmi, which in turn is a member of another tsmi, etc.?

The purpose of this is to be able to add an event handler that gets at the `TreeView` that has the `ContextMenuStrip` that has that `ToolStripMenuItem`.

Abstracting a bit, is there a general way to get at the owners of controls, until you reach the one you're interested in?  Just cast and hope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use 
ToolStripMenuItem1.GetCurrentParent()

for getting parent of controls which inherited from System.Windows.Forms.Control
read Parent

like Button1.Parent, ....

Comment: Like, how did you figure that out?  How would I figure it out in general if there was a control that is a member of other controls, and I want to get the top level control, say?

Comment: me,by experience im programmign for 10 years, so i had many problem and solved them in delphi ,c++, c# sql ...., and to for menu item itsdifferent , but all controls have  parent,which are inherited from System.Windows.Forms.Control  and you cna read Parent property of each control